# SharePoint Framework jQuery REST POST returns 400 Bad Request error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, jquery-ajax

I am totally stumped again as to what is causing my update to fail. The same process works fine using the "old" approach inside a web content editor. Now that I am using the framework the jQuery ajax call fails! Thinking that the problem was related to being in the workbench, I packaged my app add-in and installed it on my test SharePoint Online site. The problem still occurs with the same message. Here is the detail of what I am doing:

**Error:**

400 Bad Request - "The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PATCH method."

**ajax URL:**

```
https://[site URL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Job%20Tickets')/items?$filter=Id%20eq%2028
```

**Request Payload (from Chrome console)**

```
{__metadata: {type: "SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem"}, Notes: " ",…}
Completed
:
"2017-05-12T15:19:04.583Z"
Completed_x0020_By
:
"Michael Aleman"
Notes
:
"                        "
__metadata
:
{type: "SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem"}
type
:
"SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem"
```

**Json object returned from a GET**

```
    {
    "odata.metadata": "https://strattechbiz.sharepoint.com/CPMDevV1/_api/$metadata#SP.ListData.Job_x0020_TicketsListItems",
    "value": [{
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem",
        "odata.id": "53e22fbc-d5dd-4f87-b77c-57d30dda1b0d",
        "odata.etag": "\"1\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'e78373b6-db70-475f-902c-fa7e1b2b88ed')/Items(28)",
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 28,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "Title": "Aqua Systems New Website Home Page",
        "Order0Id": 1,
        "OrderLineId": 0,
        "ProcessId": 1,
        "Sequence": 0.0,
        "Activity": 0.0,
        "Days": 13.0,
        "Completed": null,
        "Activity_x0020_Description": "Order Special Instructions",
        "Special_x0020_Instructions": "<div class=\"ExternalClassA95F1BDBDDA74AF2A8DC6E45FAD89C7E\">Just a single page website. Make sure to include contact us &quot;form&quot;.</div>",
        "Notes": null,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x01009C1FBE60225CF547A736A7C52A1F3E76",
        "Completed_x0020_By": null,
        "ID": 28,
        "Modified": "2017-05-05T18:18:00Z",
        "Created": "2017-05-05T18:18:00Z",
        "AuthorId": 10,
        "EditorId": 10,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "c1a345ca-df3f-4258-8804-81c260157663"
    }]
}
```

javaScript code

```
    var getDigestCall = jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteContext.siteURLSP + '/_api/contextinfo',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept":       "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
})

getDigestCall.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    requestDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
    today= new Date();

    fullUrl = siteContext.siteURLSP + siteContext.urlJobTicketsId + jobActivity;
    var ajaxData ={
        '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem'},
        'Notes' : jQuery("#inputNotes").val(),
        'Completed_x0020_By': siteContext.currentUser,
        'Completed': today.toISOString()
        }


    jQuery.ajax({
            url: fullUrl,
            type: "Post",
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
            headers: {
                "accept":       "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest" : requestDigest,
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            },
            success: onActivityCompletedSuccess,
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
                onJobTicketsFailed(jqXHR, status, error);
            }
    });

})
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Job Tickets')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName` gives you and that should be your entityname in your POST

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had already tried that and confirmed I had the right name, but to make sure I ran it again. It returned:  "ListItemEntityTypeFullName": "SP.Data.Job_x0020_TicketsListItem". As you can see, that is the name I am using for type in the metadata.

Comment: just making sure ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Thanks to @wjervis for pointing out.

To update list item using REST API, the endpoint would be as below:

`https://[site URL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')/items(ID)`

where ID = item id of the list item.

Your full url should be somewhat as below:

`https://[site URL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Job Tickets')/items(2028)`

And your end code would be replaced as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://[site URL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Job Tickets')/items(2028)",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),             
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                
                "X-RequestDigest" : requestDigest,
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            },
            success: onActivityCompletedSuccess,
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
                onJobTicketsFailed(jqXHR, status, error);
            }
});
```

Comment: I downvoted for a few reasons.  First, headers are not case sensitive as per [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2), so `accept` will work (I know this from experience as well).  Second, since data is being sent, you have to indicate `content-type`.  Third, the encoding of the space has absolutely no impact (in fact, jQuery encodes it for you).

Comment: Just noticed that you simply moved `content-type` outside of `headers`.  It makes no difference where it is, since jQuery will do `xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", contentType);` regardless of how you do it.

Comment: It worked! The culprit was in fact the url. I was using $filter which worked as a web part but not in an app add-in. After correcting the url per Gautam's suggestion it worked. Note... I left my content-type as is in the headers section.

Comment: @ - maleman - glad that it worked.
@wjervis - i apologize for this. I agree with each and every word of your comments.  So totally deserve the downvote :( 
However, not sure what to do now ? Should i modify the answer ?

Comment: I'll remove my answer, if you want to put the bit about `/items(id)`  fixing it in yours.  The edit will allow me to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then using JQuery, you should use PnP for CRUD operations on SP list, it will reduce so much of the effort and issues that you are facing. 
Here is [Basic Operations using PnP-JS](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Basic--Operations).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pnp-js-core to do this. It's much easier to work with.